# Store types only for certain properties

Tags: c#, interface, json.net

I have very deep tree with nodes like this:

```cs
class Node {
    public string Name { get; }
    public IA A { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyList<Node> Children { get; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Node(string name, List<Node> children) { ... }
}
```

I'm trying to decrease the amount of space required to store serialized data.

I hope the serializer might be able to figure out the type for `Children` because of the corresponding parameter in the constructor. Is it possible to store type only for property `A` but not for `Children`?

For now I use the following but this is very expensive in terms of space:

```cs
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tree, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto });
```

It serializes `Children` into

```json
"Children": {
  "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Very.Long.Node, Very.Long.Structure]], mscorlib",
  ...
```

The real type is pretty complex so per-field solution would be really appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if JSON.Net supports that, but one solution might be to replicate your tree, only including the children you want to serialize, perform the serialization, and release the replicated tree to the ether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `[JsonProperty]` attribute to your `A` property, and setting the `TypeNameHandling` there.  Then remove `TypeNameHandling` from the `JsonSerializerSettings` (or just omit `JsonSerializerSettings` altogether if there aren't any other settings you need).

In other words:

```
class Node {
    public string Name { get; }

    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]   // add this
    public IA A { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<Node> Children { get; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Node(string name, List<Node> children) { ... }
}
```

Then serialize like this:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tree);
```

Here is a roundtrip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/c8LvTi